# Icon on desktop

Tags: facebook, desktop

I was doing some work when I noticed new icon on my desktop called "sl_files". I couldn't help but open it. It contains CSS files, and there is some recognized as .download files.
It has pictures of my Facebook friends and pages that I have liked or that sometimes appeared on my Facebook news feed.
Should I be worried and what should I do?
What this could mean?

Comment: Don't "open" an unrecognized file from a file explorer. (As in double clicking it and allowing the OS to choose what application to open it with.) Check the file properties to confirm that it's not an executable, shortcut, or script. Launch a text editor, hex editor, or whatever first. Then open the file using that application. Executables and shortcuts can use custom icons. It's common for malicious files to use a deceptive icon and make it look like a text file, folder, or other low risk file type. It's not necessary to risk double-click opening mysterious files.

Answer (score 1):

There is a keyboard combination in most browsers that saves the content of a link, in OS-X Chrome `option+click` does this. I know I often fat finger `command+click`(open in new tab) as `option+click`. This typo results in the browser saving the page and all resources of that page (javascript, css, images) into a folder by default on the desktop.

I would suggest that you have nothing to worry about. Delete the folder and carry on.